# Why we need to use before delete event instead of after delete in apex trigger

Tags: before-trigger, after-trigger, delete

For example:
My trigger scenario:

when account record is deleted then contact record should also be deleted.

My Implementation:

when account record is deleted then contact record should also be deleted.

```
trigger accTrigger on Account(after delete)
{
   accHandler.deleteAccount(Trigger.old);
}
```

My handler class:

```
public class accHandler
{
   public static void deleteAccount(List<Account> lstAcc)
   {
       Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();

       for(Account acc : lstAcc)
       {
           accId.add(acc.Id);
       }

       if(!accId.isEmpty())
       {
           List<Contact> conList = [Select AccountId, Name from Contact where AccountId in :accId];
           delete conList;
       }
   }
}
```

when account records deleted then contact records also be deleted when I use both after delete and before delete events so what is the difference between these two? if you can provide any example then it would be great. What I understood is, that when I use the before-delete event then we can retrieve only account records from the recycle bin using the restore option but after-delete event both account and contact records are also restored.

So is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using before-delete allows you to query the state of the database before it's modified. This is usually done to either prevent deletion using `addError`, or to provide custom delete behavior (e.g. for non-cascading deletions). Salesforce automatically deletes contacts when an account is deleted (cascading deletion), so you don't ordinarily need a trigger to deal with deleting the contacts.

If you delete the contacts in a before-delete trigger, they are deleted separately and must be restored separately from the recycle bin if you want to undelete them. You'll find you cannot delete the contacts in an after-delete trigger, because they will have already been automatically deleted due to the default cascading deletion feature. In your example code, `conList` will necessarily be empty.

Aside from that, assuming your code was dealing with a record that wasn't automatically cascade deleted, the trigger handler can be just a single line of code:

```
  delete [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :lstAcc];
```

Salesforce is smart enough to know that a list of sObjects can be mapped to an Id field without having to perform a manual extraction process.

Comment: Note the recommendation **NOT** to directly use an SObject list in SOQL where an ID list is required in [this ApexGuru article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2024/02/get-ai-powered-insights-for-your-apex-code-with-apexguru).

Comment: @PhilW I'm going to have to have a talk with them...